# How do I correctly use the Scandir()?

Tags: php, scandir

I have a directory that I am trying scan with the `scandir()`, of course, and print it to the screen.
Unfortunately, I cannot seem to do so.  I am looking for `.CSV` files in the directory.  There is one at the moment.
Host system: `Ubuntu 16.04`
Running `Apache2 Mysql`
Localhost server with `PhpAdmin`.
Directory to scan: `/var/www/html`

Code using:

```
$l = preg_grep("/var/www/html/.(CSV)$~", scandir($dir_f));
print_r("Found List of Files" + $l);
```

Comment: i suggest glob() instead `print_r(glob("/var/www/html/*.CSV"));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the PHP [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function to retrieve all the files matching a given pattern within a directory.

**Example:**

```
$matches = array();
foreach (glob('/var/www/html/*.CSV') as $f) {
  $matches[] = $f;
}
```

Comment: OK, so if I don't want to print it to the screen, but would rather open each file and put it an array, how would I manage that?  Since it is in an array I would for each it right? And then use a csvreader?

Comment: You can achieve this easily by using fgetcsv() inside this loop (https://www.php.net/fgetcsv)

Comment: Don't I have to specify the file though?  Or does it work with the loop without having to specify?  Right now there is only 1 file, but eventually there will be 300+, so I would like to automate it as much as possible

Comment: You have to use this function within a loop (so you'll have a while() inside the foreach() for instance). There's an usage example on the PHP manual, I hope this helps.